# Simple Client-Server application in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, client-server

I started to learn about server-client application and I used this Java code example for client and server:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoServer.java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/EchoClient.java

I ran both applications on two instances of Eclipse.

The code remain the same, except for the change:

```
            //out.println(inputLine);
            System.out.println(inputLine);
```

In the server side.
And to the printings "Hello", "Bye" in the beginning and end of the main() in the server-side. And of course, I set the IP used by the Client to the IP of my computer (used ipconfig - not unique IP)

From what I understand, everything the client sends should appear on the server standard output until the client types "Cntrl C" (unless I understand wrong).

here is the input I wrote in the client side:

```
boooooooooo
baaaaaa
paaaaaaa
```

And this is what I get in the Server-side:

```
Hello
boooooooooo
```

Something in here is unexpected to me-
the server seem to run in the main(),
but from some reason after the first printing it stops.

I tried o set breakpoints inside the Client side code on the while-line

`while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
       out.println(userInput);
       System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
}`

but the program flow encountered the while only twice an then didn't reach there anymore.
when it did enter in, userInput was not evaluated, I suspect because readline() returned null. But why should it? if EOF character wasn't inserted to the standard input in the Client side.

Comment: what was the value of userInput at those breakpoints? I'm pretty sure that readLine() blocks until a it receives a value, but it may actually be receiving a null value

Comment: it was not calculated. Maybe readLine() returned null. but why should this function return null when it waits for a value to arrive? I though only in the end of the stream (Cntrl C) this function returns null

Comment: try closing the writers and readers